# Como parar video do youtube quando clicar em um botão?

Tags: javascript, jquery, react, iframe, youtube

Estou fazendo um site com React e tenho um carrossel com alguns Iframes com videos do youtube, quando desliso para o próximo vídeo o anterior ainda fica reproduzindo.

Tem alguma forma com JQuery ou JS que faça parar a reprodução quando clicar em um botão?

Tem uma opção melho do que o Iframe para fazer isso?

Encontrei uma soluções com JQuery, mas ela é em uma versão muito antiga: [Solução antiga](https://codepen.io/briangelhaus/pen/meeLRO) (2.1.3) Tentei modificá-lo para uma versão mais atual mas não funcionou, sou novo no JQuery.

Esse é o código atual:

jsx

```
<div className='video-frame'>
                    <iframe className='video-frame' width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LW1D0TfMogg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                </div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.next-bt').on("click",function(){
$('.video-frame')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');});
```

Quem poder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: qual é o seu código atual?

Comment: @novic atualizei